# Stack Overflow doesn't work for me anymore; where should I look instead?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, scope

As an architect and team lead, many of the questions I'm interested in are comparisons of technologies, or accounts of how well a particular technology or methodology works in practice.

And almost all of these sorts of questions are "closed as not constructive".

This has been a frustration for several years now, and has led me to being a much less frequent user of Stack Overflow: I google, I'm happy to see that there's an answer on Stack Overflow, then I find it's been closed.

Where do you recommend that I ask these sorts of questions, or look for these sorts of answers, since they're not suited for Stack Overflow?

Comment: http://slant.co seems to be set up for just that sort of thing. There's also the currently-in-beta [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: I've yet to find a site other than SE that prohibits these questions, so...literally anywhere else?

Comment: Quora. They accept any question over there.

Comment: Doesn't need to be closed, doesn't need to be dragged into a tangential discussion.

Comment: A good way is also to join chat and speak with others in your field about things. You can listen to others talking about their own experiences with different technologies, which might help you make your own decisions later.

Comment: Quora might fit the bill. Samples: *[What are the advantages and disadvantages of writing a web application in Scala using Lift?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-writing-a-web-app-in-Scala-using-Lift)* and *[What is the best package manager for Vim plugins?](https://www.quora.com/Vim/What-is-the-best-package-manager-for-vim-plugins)*.

Answer (score 10):

As an architect and a team lead Stack Overflow is *exactly* where I want to be - I contribute regularly and encourage my team to do the same. No single resource has given me more, and what's more it's all through my own effort and research.

Yes, I can't get advice on exactly what libraries I should be using for purpose X. But, I already know what libraries among the N out there I should be using. When I don't have a clue I research the subject, have a chat with my peers and my team and come up with a solution. I've *never* felt the need to ask for a list of libraries on Stack Overflow. If you ever feel that way I highly recommend [Yannis' answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145813/179419).

I recommend that you follow Yannis' advice; if you feel a need to compare libraries that you can't decide between (often the case!) then take you time, decide what's important to you and be absolutely clear about what you're trying to decide, what you're trying to achieve and why you are where you are. That'll make a good Stack Overflow question.